# Plugin works in local server but doesn't work in production server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've a created a plugin with a button which does some task when clicking it. I've put this plugin in my local Jenkins (`/jenkins/plugins`) location and then restarted server.

The button appears on every job page, but When I put the same plugin in production server and restart it, the button doesn't appear.

Both my local Jenkins and production Jenkins have same version (2.7.1)
I put plugin.jar and plugin.hpi files in `/jenkins/plugins` location
Can anyone have idea whats the problem. How can I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a log by going to:
Manage Jenkins > System Log > Add a New Log Recorder.

Check the System Log for any loggers that are printing warnings during the Jenkins boot process, add them to the Log Recorder, and adjust the logging level to your liking.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging